# How to extract a bytes data from a string in python?

Tags: python

```
str1 = "b""T\xefD\xcdB\x95\x90v\x9f\x88^\xa3\x08\x00E\x00\x00|\xd7u@\x00.\x11\x80\xcf\x0e\xd7#\x07\xc0\xa8\x01\xa6\x1fu\xb2d\x00h}\x0e!1\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16So\xe7`\x00|\xd0j\xcc\xbc\xf5<j\x807\x98\xb1t\xddMMrH\xf1\xffy\xbd]\x88\xb1\x9f\xe04r\xaaD\xc8\xd5\x9cc\xe1\xc9'\x0e\x1dsY)4\xaeq\xf9\xe9\x8e\xc7c\xd9O\xa5I\x86\xd6p\xa5.a){\xbc\x16\xe4\xf9\x86\x15\x7f\xddw!\xa8U#I\xf5FV.\xe0k\xcf"""
b1 = b'T\xefD\xcdB\x95\x90v\x9f\x88^\xa3\x08\x00E\x00\x00|\xd7u@\x00.\x11\x80\xcf\x0e\xd7#\x07\xc0\xa8\x01\xa6\x1fu\xb2d\x00h}\x0e!1\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16So\xe7`\x00|\xd0j\xcc\xbc\xf5<j\x807\x98\xb1t\xddMMrH\xf1\xffy\xbd]\x88\xb1\x9f\xe04r\xaaD\xc8\xd5\x9cc\xe1\xc9'\x0e\x1dsY)4\xaeq\xf9\xe9\x8e\xc7c\xd9O\xa5I\x86\xd6p\xa5.a){\xbc\x16\xe4\xf9\x86\x15\x7f\xddw!\xa8U#I\xf5FV.\xe0k\xcf'
```

how to transfer str1 which is <class 'str'> to b1 which is <class 'bytes'>?

Comment: Your `"b""T\xefD\xcd…` will actually be concatenated to `"bT\xefD\xcd…`

Comment: Is there a format error in str1?

Comment: It is not exactly an error, but written like this the string becomes something different than what might be expected. It's not clear to us what the input data is exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way:

```
str1 = "b""T\xefD\xcdB\x95\x90v\x9f\x88^\xa3\x08\x00E\x00\x00|\xd7u@\x00.\x11\x80\xcf\x0e\xd7#\x07\xc0\xa8\x01\xa6\x1fu\xb2d\x00h}\x0e!1\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16So\xe7`\x00|\xd0j\xcc\xbc\xf5<j\x807\x98\xb1t\xddMMrH\xf1\xffy\xbd]\x88\xb1\x9f\xe04r\xaaD\xc8\xd5\x9cc\xe1\xc9'\x0e\x1dsY)4\xaeq\xf9\xe9\x8e\xc7c\xd9O\xa5I\x86\xd6p\xa5.a){\xbc\x16\xe4\xf9\x86\x15\x7f\xddw!\xa8U#I\xf5FV.\xe0k\xcf"""
    
b1 = bytes(str1.split("b")[1], 'raw_unicode_escape')

print (b1)
```

Output:

> b"T\xefD\xcdB\x95\x90v\x9f\x88^\xa3\x08\x00E\x00\x00|\xd7u@\x00.\x11\x80\xcf\x0e\xd7#\x07\xc0\xa8\x01\xa6\x1fu\xb2d\x00h}\x0e!1\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16So\xe7`\x00|\xd0j\xcc\xbc\xf5<j\x807\x98\xb1t\xddMMrH\xf1\xffy\xbd]\x88\xb1\x9f\xe04r\xaaD\xc8\xd5\x9cc\xe1\xc9'\x0e\x1dsY)4\xaeq\xf9\xe9\x8e\xc7c\xd9O\xa5I\x86\xd6p\xa5.a){\xbc\x16\xe4\xf9\x86\x15\x7f\xddw!\xa8U#I\xf5FV.\xe0k\xcf"

Answer (score 1):

if you have a correct format `str1`, you can try to use `eval`

code:

```
str1 = r'b"T\xefD\xcdB\x95\x90v\x9f\x88^\xa3\x08\x00E\x00\x00|\xd7u@\x00.\x11\x80\xcf\x0e\xd7#\x07\xc0\xa8\x01\xa6\x1fu\xb2d\x00h}\x0e!1\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16So\xe7`\x00|\xd0j\xcc\xbc\xf5<j\x807\x98\xb1t\xddMMrH\xf1\xffy\xbd]\x88\xb1\x9f\xe04r\xaaD\xc8\xd5\x9cc\xe1\xc9\'\x0e\x1dsY)4\xaeq\xf9\xe9\x8e\xc7c\xd9O\xa5I\x86\xd6p\xa5.a){\xbc\x16\xe4\xf9\x86\x15\x7f\xddw!\xa8U#I\xf5FV.\xe0k\xcf"'
x = eval(str1)
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

result:

```
b"T\xefD\xcdB\x95\x90v\x9f\x88^\xa3\x08\x00E\x00\x00|\xd7u@\x00.\x11\x80\xcf\x0e\xd7#\x07\xc0\xa8\x01\xa6\x1fu\xb2d\x00h}\x0e!1\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16So\xe7`\x00|\xd0j\xcc\xbc\xf5<j\x807\x98\xb1t\xddMMrH\xf1\xffy\xbd]\x88\xb1\x9f\xe04r\xaaD\xc8\xd5\x9cc\xe1\xc9'\x0e\x1dsY)4\xaeq\xf9\xe9\x8e\xc7c\xd9O\xa5I\x86\xd6p\xa5.a){\xbc\x16\xe4\xf9\x86\x15\x7f\xddw!\xa8U#I\xf5FV.\xe0k\xcf" 
<class 'bytes'>
```